# KD-Tree and Ball-Tree algorithm appearing wrong (to my untrained eye)

Tags: python, pyspark, kdtree

The KD-Tree and Ball-Tree algorithm are giving me unexpected results in a new pyspark notebook running on databricks.

I have created a new databricks notebook (pyspark) and copied the following code in:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
matrix = np.array([
          [0, 1, 4, 2, 1],
          [1, 0, 2, 1, 1],
          [4, 2, 0, 3, 1],
          [2, 1, 3, 0, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
      ])
tree = BallTree(matrix)
dist, ind = tree.query(matrix, k=5)
print(ind)
```

And the ind output is:

```
[[0 1 3 4 2]
 [1 4 3 0 2]
 [2 4 1 3 0]
 [3 1 4 0 2]
 [4 1 3 0 2]]
```

My expectation would be that the first row should read [[0 1 4 3 2] or it should read [[0 4 1 3 2], rather than [[0 1 3 4 2]. Have I missed something / misunderstood? The same also occurs when I use a KDTree instead of a ball tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take into account that `BallTree` and `KDTree` took as their inputs the **coordianates** of points in N-dim space (not the matrix of pairwise distances). The following calculation proves that the result returned by `BallTree` is correct:

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

distance_matrix(X, X)**2

# output
array([[ 0.,  7., 34.,  9., 12.],
       [ 7.,  0., 21.,  4.,  3.],
       [34., 21.,  0., 23., 16.],
       [ 9.,  4., 23.,  0.,  7.],
       [12.,  3., 16.,  7.,  0.]])

(distance_matrix(X, X)**2).argsort(axis=1)

# output
array([[0, 1, 3, 4, 2],
       [1, 4, 3, 0, 2],
       [2, 4, 1, 3, 0],
       [3, 1, 4, 0, 2],
       [4, 1, 3, 0, 2]])
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you, so if I just want the output I previously expected I can use argsort(axis = 1).

Comment: Absolutely right, if you have already had the distance matrix, it's enough just to sort distances to obtain the indexes of the nearest points.

`BallTree` and `KDTree` are intended for situations when you need to find the nearest neighbours for some new points as fast as possible. Ones constructed, they calculate the nearest neighbour for the given point via `O(log(N))` distance calculations (where `N` is the size of training set) - compare with complexity `O(N)` in naive approach.